# Method Overridding Access modifier and Return Type Restriction

Tags: java, access-modifiers, overriding

Following code works according to the rules of method Overriding and shows a compilation error Incompatible return type with Base.aMethod()

```
class Base
{
    Integer aMethod()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class OverRidingRules extends Base
{
    protected Number aMethod()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But if I change the access modifier of the Base.aMethod from default to private it compiles successfully. Can somebody tell me why the compiler does not show the same error?

Comment: If `aMethod()` in `Base` is `private`, it can't be overridden as it isn't visible in child classes, so what you end up doing is defining a second method that just happens to have the same name. As this second method is independent of all other methods, it has no restrictions on its return value.

Answer (score 4):

An overriding method can't have a "wider" return type than the method it overrides<sup>1</sup>, which is what you're doing here. `aMethod` from `Base` can *only* return an `Integer`, so it isn't valid to override it with something that can return any `Number` including, for example, `Float`s. This is why you are receiving the compilation error in your current code.

Now, when you change `aMethod` in `Base` to be `private`, it can no longer be seen/overriden in subclasses. Therefore, in that case, `aMethod` in `OverRidingRules` is not overriding `aMethod` in `Base` but is rather an independent method with the same name, so we don't encounter the same problem as above and no compilation error occurs.

[@user3580294](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580294/user3580294) points all this out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144204/method-overridding-access-modifier-and-return-type-restriction#comment37256848_24144204) as well.

---

<sup>1</sup> The reverse is valid, however. For example, the following would have been legal:

```
class Base {
    Number aMethod() {   // notice the return type is `Number`
        return 0;
    }
}

class OverRidingRules extends Base {
    Integer aMethod() {  // notice the return type is `Integer`
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In other words, an overriding method *can* have a "narrower" return type than the method it overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the first comment on my question had answered my question perfectly.